# How to avoid sharp turns in PgRouting?

Tags: pgrouting, route

I need to generate routes that will be performed in long vehicles. The path can not have curves 90 degrees because the streets are narrow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it in pgrouting exactly, but you could assign some high cost value to the 90 degree turns in your road network.  That way, pgrouting would "skip" those turns as it computes the route.

This seems to be one way to do it:

http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/trsp/doc/index.html

Hope that helps

Comment: I was wondering about something similar, except it starts to get complicated when you consider turn direction.  For instance, if you have an oblique road junction, turning left from the main road off on to the side road might OK (<<90).  Turning right from the side road onto the main road is also OK but turning left from the side road on to the main road would not be acceptable (>>90).